# Output of the program, when a global variable is re-declared as a local variable

Tags: c

I have initialized a global variable with value 5, and then initialized a local variable with the same name.

When I execute the below code using gcc compiler

```
//Code 1
#include<stdio.h>

int var = 5;
int main()
{
  int var = var;
  printf("%d",var);
}
```

> the output is 0

If I modify the code as follows and compile with gcc,

```
//Code 2
#include<stdio.h>

int var = 5;
int main()
{
  int v = var;
  printf("%d %d",v, var);
}
```

> the output is 5 5

If I modify the code as follows and compile with g++,

```
//Code 3 
#include<stdio.h>

int var = 5;
int main()
{
  int var = var;
  printf("%d %d",var, ::var);
}
```

> the output is 0 5

I think that the value 0 is because the compiler is initializing it to default value(https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597491)

I have tried using gcc -g Code_1 and running gdb on the output binary, and inserted a breakpoint on

> line no 4(int var = 5;)
>
> line no 7(int var = var;)
>
> line no 8(printf("%d",var);)

But on running the program the execution stops at line no 8, and `print var` outputs `$1 = 0`.
When I step out of code `0x00007ffff7e07223 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6`, the output of `print var` is `5`.

Please help me with my following queries:

1. Why is the program printing value `0` and neither reporting an error nor using the global value?
2. i. Does C have scope resolution operator `::`, like C++?

   ii. If no, then how can we use local and global variable with same name?

   iii. How can I check the value of both global and local `var`, using gdb?
3. Why doesn't the gdb encounter a breakpoint before main()?

Comment: please dont spam tags, its rather rare the the answer is the same for two different languages

Answer (score 2):

> I think that the value 0 is because the compiler is initializing it to default value

No. The local `var` is used as its own initialiser. Since its value is indeterminate before initialisation, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> 1. Why is the program printing value 0 and neither reporting an error nor using the global value?

The behaviour is undefined.

> 2. i. Does C have scope resolution operator `::`, like C++?

No.

> ii. If no, then how can we use local and global variable with same name?

There is no equivalent operator in C. You cannot access both variables in a single expression.